Base64 using GetFileAsync Office Js Add-in not working
I have an Excel add-in in this I am using this function to get Base64.
export function getBookBase64() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Compressed, { sliceSize: 4194304 }, async function (result) {
  if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
    const myFile = result.value;
    const sliceCount = myFile.sliceCount;
    const docdataSlices = [];
    let slicesReceived = 0;
    let gotAllSlices = true;

    // Get all the file slices.
    try {
      await getSliceAsync(myFile, 0, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived);
      const base64Data = await onGotAllSlices(docdataSlices); // Get base64Data from slices
      resolve(base64Data); // Resolve with base64 data
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  } else {
    reject("Error: " + result.error.message);
  }
});
});
}

So when I got base64 properly, this worked well, but now when I try to convert base64 to Excel using any web converter, after that, when I open my workbook, it shows a task pane error.
you can see the image of Error Screen

I don't want to save any add-in information because I will send my workbook to someone who has not installed my add-in.
what should be the solution? if you need any further information please leave comment
